# Unable to read request from android using HttpUrlConnection in PHP

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

following is my android code

```
...

protected Void doInBackground(JSONObject...params){

...

//connecting and writing request to server
         mycon.connect();
         OutputStream out = mycon.getOutputStream();
         out.write(params[0].toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
         Log.d("jp2: Your Request :",params[0].toString());
         //out.flush();
         int status = mycon.getResponseCode();
         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mycon.getInputStream()));
         response=br.readLine();
         Log.d("jp2", "Your response from php "+response+" : " + status);
...
```

my php code which returns the same request to android

```
...
$con=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$database);
$json = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
echo "Hello from PHP your request is :";
echo $json;
...
```

and here is my output in android monitor

```
02-17 08:11:58.515 7865-7880/com.srt.ujn.am D/jp2: Your Request :: {"mobile_no":"1234567890","cust_name":"jai","address":"surat","city":"Split AC","prod_cat":"Split AC","issue_type":"Repair"}

02-17 08:11:58.540 7865-7880/com.srt.ujn.am D/jp2: Your response from php Hello from PHP your reqest is :  : 200
```

as u can see I am getting null as output from php. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have 2 main problems: a) Are you getting your data from a file or from MySQL? That's not very clear in your PHP code, so maybe, you're not retrieving any data at all. b) You're not encoding the $json to a real JSON output.

Comment: No, i am trying to simply redirect the request string as it is to android without doing any database operations. Request from server is JSON string so i am not encoding it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed following line

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
```

to

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

and got desired output

```
02-17 09:04:42.145 7865-7879/com.srt.ujn.am D/jp2: Your Request :: {"mobile_no":"1234567890","cust_name":"jai","address":"surat","city":"Split AC","prod_cat":"Split AC","issue_type":"Repair"}
02-17 09:04:42.159 7865-7879/com.srt.ujn.am D/jp2: Your response from php Hello from PHP your reqest is :{"mobile_no":"1234567890","cust_name":"jai","address":"surat","city":"Split AC","prod_cat":"Split AC","issue_type":"Repair"}  : 200
```